# Does chocolate ice cream tend to have more salt than strawberry or vanilla?

Tags: salt, ice-cream

To the question [Why does chocolate ice cream melt faster than others?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2679/16035) I [wrote an answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/111065/16035) that suggests that it's not because of chocolate ice cream's dark color, but instead because of a lower melting point of chocolate ice cream due to more salt.

Salt depresses the melting point which is why it is put on roads and sidewalks in the winter in some cold parts of the world, *and why salt is added to the ice water bath when making ice cream.*

I'm wondering if there could be some truth to this theory, so I'd like to ask chocolate ice cream tend to have more salt than strawberry or vanilla?

Comment: See also: [Why don't most ice cream recipes include salt in the base?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/59408/20413)

Comment: This seems like the OP could trivially find information via google, and also like a generalization is very hard to make.

Comment: @Mr.Boy anybody can find one recipe or another, but only someone versed in the art of making ice cream will be familiar with the typical range of amounts of salts in each of several different flavors. That kind of experience is way beyond what google can do for us.

Comment: @uhoh in many countries, such as UK, it is a legal requirement to show exactly much salt is in food. As one example, https://www.haagen-dazs.co.uk/products/duo-dark-chocolate-salted-caramel-crunch

Comment: @Mr.Boy if you can check *several flavors for several companies* that way, you can begin to formulate an answer with some level of certainty. If you can do all of that with google somehow, *kudos!*

Comment: So as I said, you can answer this yourself. Google the leading ice cream makers. Collate the results. Or just ask someone else to do it for you...

Comment: @Mr.Boy posting a question in Stack Exchange is better because it leads to the *posting of answers* for all future readers to see. "Why don't you google it" comments are unproductive in Stack Exchange, they miss the whole point of the site. Go to the main SE meta's [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) and click [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/303080) and check out *all of the answers there.*

Answer (score 2):

Not at the supermarket I'd buy mine from. I've checked a couple of chocolate and a couple of vanilla ice creams (one cheap and one mid range of each). They all have about 0.1% salt, and most of this will come from the cow's milk (that contains some naturally occurring salt). Only one has salt on the ingredients list. It's a chocolate one but has no more salt in the nutrition information than any of the others - probably because there's less milk in that one.

This is in the UK, and you may not be, so I suggest you check the brands available to you. I wouldn't be at all surprised if American ice cream, for example, was more likely to have added salt

Comment: Thanks for the info! That's a good idea. Things like cheese and ice cream are not very popular whereI live and the ingredients are usually written in logogram, but next time I'm out I'll see if I can find something.